# get_avatar() and get_avatar_url() filter pass requested size

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I'm using a custom avatar upload overriding default gravatars. It creates two files in my uploads/avatars/ folder:

```
$smallavatar = $userid.'-60x60'.$ext;
$bigavatar = $userid.'-300x300'.$ext;
```

Then I have a filter for get_avatar() and get_avatar_url():

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'pbg_avatar', 1, 5 );

function pbg_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size ) {

    //some code here

    $curavatar = '/var/www/mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/'.$user->data->ID;
    $avalink = '/wp-content/uploads/avatars/'.$user->data->ID;

    // THIS SEEMS TO BE NOT WORKING
    if ($size < 31) { 
        $sizer = '-60x60';
    } else {
        $sizer = '-300x300';
    }

    // CHECK AVATAR
    if ( file_exists( $curavatar.'-300x300.jpg')) { 
        $avalink = $avalink.$sizer.'.jpg';
        $avatar = "<img alt='{$alt}' src='{$avalink}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    }

    return $avatar;
}
```

Then, when I'm calling it with a filtered function:

```
get_avatar($userid, 30 );
or
get_avatar_url( $userid, array('size' => 19))
```

I'm always geting the big avatar with 300x300 size, so obviously check for size in a function pbg_avatar doesn't work. How do I properly check it?

Comment: Update: ajaxed call returns correct size. But on page load its 300x300

Comment: not sure if it triggered any error for you but you missing semicolon ; after return $avatar

Comment: If you use custom avatars you might want check `pre_get_avatar_data` filter which can retrieve the avatar URL early so the default WP Gravatar will be skipped. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_avatar_data/

Comment: @Artem I already skip default gravatars, this is not the problem I have experienced. I get the correct custom avatar already, but I get wrong size of it.

Answer (score 1):

do you have any plugin that do something with avatar? your filter priority is 1, which is very low and have a high chances that its overrided by any plugin. For testing purposes, set very high priority. Also you say to the filter that you pass 5 variables while you pass only 3, just in case try to set everything correctly, so try:

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'pbg_avatar' , 999 , 3 );
```

and see if it helped.

To understand more about add_filter arguments, [read here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

---

**EDIT:**

You can check everything within the function.. for example to see if it gets all variables correctly, simply echo the variables.

for example, just before return do:

```
echo "
---------- DEBUGGING -----------<br>
size: {$size} <br>
sizer: {$sizer} <br>
avalink: {$avalink} <br>
-------------------------------<br>
";
```

and check if $size received is correct.

Comment: get_avatar() filter started working properly when I fixed the amount of variables and priority, however get_avatar_url() filter still returns a big image, instead of a small.

Comment: @SamTyurenkov that would be because get_avatar_url have its own hook as well, so you need to create similar filter function that will return url, but for [get_avatar_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar_url/) hook.

Comment: well, i forgot to add it in a question, but I had it. it returns url, but for 300x300 avatar, not 60x60